# WorkManager is cancelled after phone goes into doze mode on Samsung Galaxy phones

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat, android-8.0-oreo, android-workmanager

I am trying to run background service with WorkManager. I started WorkManager when app goes to background. And I also started background service whenever WorkManger is running. I can see my app service after app went background. Also I can see that it is started after about 15 minutes from when I closed app by swiping in app list. So I am sure workmanager is working at start time. But I think it is not working on doze mode. I could not see my service after waking the phone from doze mode, too.

My code:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

  public MyWorker() {
    super();
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public WorkerResult doWork() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        MyJobIntentService.enqueueWork(getApplicationContext(), new Intent());
    } else {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(intent);
    }

    return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
  }
}

public void startWorkManger() {

  PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest
         .Builder(MyWorker.class, MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).addTag(TAG).build();
  mWorkManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: did you get your solution? if yes then Mention here to help other.

Answer (score 0):

JobScheduler will only execute jobs in maintenance intervals when in Doze mode. This is being done to conserve the user's battery. So what you are seeing is expected.

For more information read this documentation on Doze mode.
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby